# About methods and to create another method

Tags: java

I'm beginner in Java and I have a basic question about main method

```
public class Main {
  final static int a=10;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
  public void hai(){
    int b=1;
    System.out.println(b);
  }
}
```

For above code I am unable to get the o/p for hai method

Comment: Well, you never call it for one. As a side note, *please* take the time to format your code. You're asking for help from people who volunteer your time, the *least* you can do is at least make sure your code is readable. In addition, showing any attempts at solving the problem is usually a good idea. Right now it looks like you're saying "Here's my code, it isn't working, bye", which really isn't the kind of question that should be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Add `new Main().hai();` to your `main` method

Comment: Could anyone explain what o/p means here for my learning purpose?

Comment: @KickButtowski My guess is "output"

Comment: @user3580294 r u sure?

Comment: @KickButtowski Not totally sure, but it's the only word that makes sense to me every time I see "o/p". I have no clue where that abbreviation came from though.

Comment: Of course @user3580294 is correct, according to electrical terms may be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with this code.  I have made a revised version of it, with comments to help you understand why it would not work.

```
public class Main {
    //There is no reason to use public, final, or static on this int variable
    int a = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Cannot print a, as main is a static method and a is out of it's scope
        //System.out.println(a);

        //Creates new "Main" object, calls hai method
        Main m = new Main();
        m.hai();
    }

    public void hai() {
        int b = 1;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

When we create the "Main" object, we are creating an *instance* of this class.  An instance is simply an Object created from a class.  In this example that object is **Main**.  Once this instance is created, we are able to call all of the methods located inside Main, (including the 'hai' method)

Also, ensure your Main class surrounds all of your methods.
Your class contains all of the methods needed to perform your file's functions.  You will not have two classes inside one file, nor will you write much outside of the class declaration, (excluding imports, etc).